# Using WITH TIES to retrieve multiple rows with same value

Tags: sqlite, top

I am relatively new to SQLite. I have a database called "Clothes Catalog" that contains info on each data point's item type (shirts, pants, etc), catalog ID, and price.

I want to retrieve the maximum price of an item of each type, the item type, and the catalog ID. If two items within a type have the same price, I want both catalog ID's to be included.

I tried this query but it does not run, any ideas why?

```
  SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES itemtype, catalogID, price
  from clothes_catalog
  group by itemtype
  order by catalogID ASC;
```

Lets say my table looks like this:

```
 shirt, 20456, $16
 shirt, 23456, $18
 pant, 2222, $20
 pant, 4444, $20
 pant, 5656, $15
```

I want the following to show, and ALSO have catalogID in ascending order:

```
 pant, 2222, $20
 pant, 4444, $20
 shirt, 23456, $18
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Just to add an explanation "why": because `TOP` is not standard SQL (it's specific to MS SQL Server), likewise for `WITH TIES`. SQLite's version of `TOP` is [`LIMIT`](http://sqlite.org/lang_select.html#limitoffset) (which also isn't standard, although it's a more common variant than `TOP`). The "standard" is [`FETCH FIRST`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT) which (AFAIK) you'll only find in Postgres and DB2! Welcome to the many not-quite-compatible varieties of SQL...

Answer (score 2):

This query returns the maximum price for each type:

```
SELECT itemtype,
       max(price)
FROM clothes_catalog
GROUP BY itemtype;
```

To get all items with that price, join these results back to the original table:

```
SELECT itemtype,
       catalogID,
       price
FROM clothes_catalog
JOIN (SELECT itemtype,
             max(price) AS price
      FROM clothes_catalog
      GROUP BY itemtype
     )
     USING (itemtype, price)
ORDER BY catalogID;
```